# Content Delivery Network Cache Mechanism

Tags: caching, cloudflare, cdn

I have few question on CDN cache-

1. How does client knows to hit CDN and not original server? Does original server redirects or CDN is directly called by some method like link to CDN?
2. When for the first time CDN sources data from original server, does it caches data to the server closest to client or to all CDN servers?
3. TTL at CDN differs than TTL at browser for the same response that is being cached?

Thanks you!

I searched on internet a lot. found a few incomplete answers. Looking for complete and accruate answer here. Can someone please help?